# Problems With My Project(Django Database)

Tags: python, django

I am working on an app with django I am right now still trying to create the database for it the problem is that my database is using a time field and I have never used it before what I wish to do is add a default value to it which is 0min 0sec.

```
time_taken = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, default="", null=True)
```

This is the code I have written for it.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#timefield)

> A time, represented in Python by a datetime.time instance.

so something in a line of following:

```
time_taken = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.time, null=True)
```

Comment: so this by defaut would make the time 0min and 0sec right